How to deal with ill conditioned optimization problem (Sinkhorn barycenter)
Problematic (Debiased Sinkhorn barycenter, proposed by H.Janti et al.):  Let $\alpha_1, \ldots, \alpha_K \in \Delta_n$ and $\mathbf{K}=e^{-\frac{\mathrm{C}}{\varepsilon}}$. Let $\pi$ denote a sequence $\pi_1, \ldots, \pi_K$ of transport plans in $\mathbb{R}_{+}^{n \times n}$ and the constraint sets $\mathcal{H}_1=\left\{\pi \mid \forall k, \pi_k \mathbb{1}=\alpha_k\right\}$, and $\mathcal{H}_2=\left\{\pi \mid \forall k \forall k^{\prime}, \pi_k^{\top} \mathbb{1}=\pi_{k^{\prime}} \mathbb{1}\right\}$. The barycenter problem $\min _{\alpha \in \Delta_n} \sum_{k=1}^K w_k \mathrm{~S}_{\varepsilon}\left(\alpha_k, \alpha\right)$ is equivalent to:
\begin{align*}
& \min _{\substack{\pi \in \mathcal{H}_1 \cap \mathcal{H}_2 \\
d \in \mathbb{R}_{+}^n}}\left[\varepsilon \sum_{k=1}^K w_k \mathrm{KL}\left(\pi_k \mid \mathbf{K} \operatorname{diag}(d)\right) +\frac{\varepsilon}{2}\langle d-\mathbb{1}, \mathbf{K}(d-\mathbb{1})\rangle\right]. \tag{3.}
\end{align*}
where $\mathrm{KL}(\mathbf{P} \mid \mathbf{Q})=\sum_{i, j} \mathbf{P}_{i j} \log \left(\frac{\mathbf{P}_{i j}}{\mathbf{Q}_{i j}}\right)+\mathbf{Q}_{i j}-\mathbf{P}_{i j}$.
To compute the barycenter numerically, we can use Algorithm 1 in the same paper of Janati.
Comments: Algorithm 1 solves the problem quite efficiently with many examples although there is no proof of convergence. However, I found an issue that when the matrix $\mathbf{K}$ has a large condition number, this algorithm is not stable anymore and I have to change the value of $\varepsilon$ to be suitable (but this is not a general way). So, I am trying to reduce the effect of the matrix $\mathbf{K}$ by setting $v = K^{1/2}(d - \mathbb{1})$ and optimize the objective function over this new variable $v$. I wonder if you could give me some idea to implement or improve this algorithm better.

First attempt - Enhancing the convexity (it would be appreciate if you could help me check the gradient computation)

Based on the observation of the above figure, we would like to predict that a part of the optimization problem (3.) is \emph{too flat} in some directions. The convexity of the map $d \mapsto \langle (d-\mathbb{1}), \mathbf{K}(d-\mathbb{1}) \rangle$ is directly related to the eigenvalues of $\mathbf{K}$ (since the Hessian matrix is $\nabla^2 = 2\mathbf{K}$), i.e,

If the eigenvalues of $\mathbf{K}$ are large, this quadratic mapping
will have a steep curvature, leading to stronger convexity.
Otherwise, in case the eigenvalues of $\mathbf{K}$ are small
(corresponding to the case when $\varepsilon$ is very large), the
quadratic form will be flatter, leading to weaker convexity. If some
eigenvalues are very small (close to zero), the function can be
nearly flat in some directions, causing ill-conditioning and slow
convergence in optimization algorithms.


Hence, we try to enhance the convexity by setting $v = \mathbf{K}^{1/2}(d-\mathbb{1})$. In this new setting, the objective function now becomes
\begin{align*}
    L(\pi, v) & = \varepsilon \sum_{k=1}^K w_k \mathrm{KL}\left(\pi_k \mid \mathbf{K} \operatorname{diag}(\mathbf{K}^{-1/2}v + \mathbb{1})\right) +\frac{\varepsilon}{2}\Vert v \Vert^2. \tag{4.}
\end{align*}
The new objective function still remains jointly convex. Minimizing (4.) w.r.t the variable $\pi$ leads to the barycenter problem $\alpha_{\operatorname{OT}_\varepsilon^{\mathcal{U}}}$ with the modified kernel $\mathbf{K}\operatorname{diag}(d)$ (can be solved via Iterative Bregman projection algorithm). On the other hand, minimizing w.r.t the variable $d$ will lead to solving the equation
\begin{align*}
    0 &=\nabla_v L(\pi, v)\\
    0 &=\nabla_v\left[ \varepsilon \sum_{k} w_k \sum_{i,j=1}^n\left(-\pi^k_{ij}\log(\mathbf{K}^{-1/2}v+1)_j + \mathbf{K}_{ij}(\mathbf{K}^{-1/2}v+\mathbb{1})_j\right) \right] + \varepsilon v\\
    0 & = \sum_{k=1}^K w_k\sum_{j}\sum_i \left(-\pi^k_{ij}\dfrac{\mathbf{K}^{-1/2}_j}{(\mathbf{K}^{-1/2}v + \mathbb{1})_j} + \mathbf{K}_{ij}\mathbf{K}^{-1/2}_j\right) + \varepsilon v\\
    0 & = \sum_{k=1}^K w_k \sum_{j=1}^n \dfrac{\mathbf{K}^{-1/2}_j}{(\mathbf{K}^{-1/2}v + \mathbb{1})_j} (-\pi^{k^T} \mathbb{1})_j + \sum_{i,j} \mathbf{K}_{ij}\mathbf{K}^{-1/2}_j + \varepsilon v\\
    0 & = \sum_{k=1}^K w_k \sum_{j=1}^n \dfrac{-\mathbf{K}^{-1/2}_j}{(\mathbf{K}^{-1/2}v + \mathbb{1})_j} \alpha[j] + \sum_{i,j} \mathbf{K}_{ij}\mathbf{K}^{-1/2}_j + \varepsilon v\\
    0 &= \sum_{j=1}^n \dfrac{-\mathbf{K}^{-1/2}_j}{(\mathbf{K}^{-1/2}v + \mathbb{1})_j} \alpha[j] + \sum_{i,j} \mathbf{K}_{ij}\mathbf{K}^{-1/2}_j + \varepsilon v\\
    0 &= \sum_{j=1}^n \dfrac{-\mathbf{K}^{-1/2}_j}{(\mathbf{K}^{-1/2}v + \mathbb{1})_j} \alpha[j] + \sum_{j} \mathbf{K}^{-1/2}_j (\mathbf{K}^T \mathbb{1})_j + \varepsilon v\\
    0 & = \sum_{j=1}^n \left(\dfrac{-\alpha[j]}{(\mathbf{K}^{-1/2}v + \mathbb{1})_j} + (\mathbf{K}^T\mathbb{1})_j\right) \mathbf{K}^{-1/2}_j + \varepsilon v.
\end{align*}
where $\mathbf{K}^{-1/2}_j$ denotes for the row $j$ of the matrix $\mathbf{K}^{-1/2}$ and $\alpha[j]$ denotes for the $j-$component of the sequence of barycenters.
